# How to set end date inside DatePickerTimeline flutter

Tags: date, flutter, datepicker

I am using this package `https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline#-readme-tab-` to show date.. but I get confused, is there a way to set end date in this package.. for example I want to show a date from first May until last May of this year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plugins constructor

```
DatePicker(
    this.startDate, {
    Key key,
    this.width = 60,
    this.height = 80,
    this.controller,
    this.monthTextStyle = defaultMonthTextStyle,
    this.dayTextStyle = defaultDayTextStyle,
    this.dateTextStyle = defaultDateTextStyle,
    this.selectedTextColor = Colors.white,
    this.selectionColor = AppColors.defaultSelectionColor,
    this.initialSelectedDate,
    this.daysCount = 500,
    this.onDateChange,
    this.locale = "en_US",
}) : super(key: key);
```

Its not supported but you could set the no of days count `this.daysCount = 500,`